# Are there any profilers you would recommend for asp.net based applications running on in house WCF services?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3

There are couple of WCF services running and I would like to profile them and the asp.net front ends which are dependent on them.

Are there any profiles that you recommend which can help me analyse the performance of the application?

Answer (score 1):

Try the **mvc-mini-profiler** *(A simple but effective mini-profiler for **ASP.NET** and **WCF**)*:

http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

> MVC Mini Profiler was designed by the team at Stack Overflow. It is in
>   production use there and on the Stack Exchange family of sites.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use the VS built-in profiler? I recently profiled WCF service with it. [Visual Studio Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx)

Comment: It's version specific so it will depend on what VS installation the OP has.

Comment: Then Xander's and Roy's suggestions are probably the best for you if you want to profile CPU. For memory profiling you can use free CLR profiler from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you need to measure performance of the WCF services independently of your client front-end, I suggest the Ants Performance Profiler (http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler). It is very powerful and easy to use.

You can also use this to measure ASP.NET performance.

For MVC performance, you cannot go wrong using the MVC Mini Profiler, as Xander already suggested.